How to compare between two text files to find a missing word that we want with Notepad++?
How to compare between two text files to find a missing word that we want with Notepad++?
In my case, I'd translated txt from English to Thai but sometimes \n is missing from many lines.
So I want to compare between these two files to find the line that missing \n to add it by myself.
Any suggestions?


Please post your data as text, not image.

the two files are completely different... you cannot compare them as text

I don't think this is something that should be done automatically - it requires knowledge of the languages in question, and whether a new line character is even relevant there in the translated side. For example, it may be that the new-lines on EN are there for purely formatting reasons, where those reasons don't apply or aren't needed on the TH side.

If you're translating a game, \n might be used to prevent text from clipping through an area where it should be, if the game doesn't do that automatically. In that case, you can just measure how much characters can fit in the area and "cut" the strings with \n every X characters.
Basically if a dialog box can fit only 50 characters in width you can just put \n after every 50 characters, janky solution, but might be better than just mimicking \n placement from English text

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
